# Can we Apply Group By on two columns in Sql Server 2017?

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to get last message of all users who did chat with UserID 1. I want to apply group by on two feilds. The Database is like:

```
MessageID    Message    MessageCreatorUserID     MessageRecieverUserID   CreatedAt

  1           HI                  4                         1              
  2           Hello               1                         3             
  3           Bye                 1                         3                       
  4           Thanks              1                         2
  5           hii                 1                         3
```

This is table and My question is:

UserID is stored in MessageCreatorUserID or MessageRecieverUserID

I want to get last message of all users, who did the chat with UserID 1.

Comment: A chat with UserId = 1means the user 1 is the Creator or Receiver of a message, right ?

Comment: Could you show us what you have tried?

Comment: UserID is stored in MessageCreatorUserID or MessageRecieverUserID

Comment: Not sure what GROUP BY has to do with this. Perhaps you can explain this a little bit? From the data posted what do you expect as output? It looks like all of the data involves UserID 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you can use window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by (case when MessageCreatorUserId = 1 then MessageReceiverUserId else MessageCreatorUserId end)
                                order by messageId desc
                               ) as seqnum
      from t
      where 1 in (MessageCreatorUserId, MessageReceiverUserId)
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: This is the thing what I was looking for. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I think you are mixing up group by and where clause.

Get all the messages where UserId = 1 is in MessageCreatorUserId or MessageReceiverUserId :

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE MessageCreatorUserId = 1 OR MessageReceiverUserId  = 1
```

Now we want the lastMessage from each conversation :

```
 SELECT MAX(MessageID), MessageCreatorUserId 
 FROM table1 
 WHERE MessageCreatorUserId = 1 OR MessageReceiverUserId  = 1
 GROUP BY MessageCreatorUserId
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a a join between a conditional grouping and the main table that you need:

```
select g.otheruser, t.message from (
  SELECT  
    case 
      when MessageCreatorUserId = 1 then MessageRecieverUserID
      else MessageCreatorUserId
    end otheruser,
    MAX(MessageID) maxid
  FROM tablename 
  WHERE MessageCreatorUserId = 1 OR MessageRecieverUserID  = 1
  GROUP BY 
    case 
      when MessageCreatorUserId = 1 then MessageRecieverUserID
      else MessageCreatorUserId
    end 
) g inner join tablename t
on t.messageid = g.maxid
order by otheruser
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=f6c8e6362938d88a932e80d8bfb42b9e)